# fresh git checkout not pulling down most recent commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running git as part of a `Jenkinsfile` jenkins job and when I clone one of my repos into a new directory on my Jenkins node, in my logs I see this:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
Cloning the remote Git repository
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 0c25e24630a388bcfebdb363ed6de92c5bcb9852
 > git rev-list --no-walk ea4220293a9dede0ce739ecc9169679c516cb274 # timeout=10
Checking out Revision c9210654c796880d8969320768cc683572e430d1 (origin/master)
Commit message: "Releasing gem-tardis to gem-dev-03"
```

The `git checkout -f 0c25e246....` command is great! Just the commit required. So why does it then decide to check out `Revision c9210654....` which is the previous commit?

This is my Jenkins git plugin command in the Jenkinsfile that is obviously making these decisions for me - how can I tell it not to ignore the most recent commit?

```
        checkout([
                $class           : 'GitSCM',
                branches         : [[name: 'master']],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[
                                       credentialsId: config.git.cred,
                                       url          : config.git.rootRepoUrl
                                    ]]])
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the default checkout?

Comment: The Jenkins documentation seems to vary: some of it is poor, some of it is wrong, and the rest of it does not exist. So Jenkins itself is inexplicable. This has nothing to do with *Git*, though, which is just checking out the commit that Jenkins asks for.